# Configure Sql Server 2008 r2 remote access by ip address

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working with sql server 2008 r2 on running windows 7. here, i'm getting one problem with remote access of sql server. I'm using one system as server system for data storage and other system's are using server data by Lan network. In Lan, every thing is fine to work. But when i'm trying to access the server data by public ip address, it's can't connected and i don't know properly how to configure by the IP address. The server system have internet connection and getting by the router.

So, how to access sql server data by the outside of the lan (By internet by another place) and how to configure? could you anybody assist this issue, please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Work out what port the SQL Server is running on. Ensure it is static, not dynamic. Lets say it's 1433
2. Work out what the SQL Servers internal LAN IP address is (it will be 192.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x). Lets say it's 192.168.1.12
3. Work out what the internet facing address is (it won't be 192.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x. This is the 'other side of your router)
4. Pick a port number that you want to use on the internet side, say port 1893
5. Now configure your router to forward incoming requests in port 1893 to port 1433, address 192.168.1.12

This is called 'NAT' or network address translation. It is configured in the firewall part of your router.

Comment: Just keep in mind this opens your SQL Server to the internet. Make sure you have very  strong passwords, and as few logins as possible, and make sure they are low security logins. For example if you leave the `sa` login active then then you are just asking for trouble.